# not rendering alpha chanel as seen in the composite note

Tags: rendering, transparency

What I want to do is simply to render a green screen video clip as an alpha file on top of an image. Everything looks good in the compositing mode. Problem is: Blender does not render what is shown in the composite node, it just re–render the green–screen video clip ignoring all nodes connected to it. I have tried to render it as an alpha file (out put as: MPEG, format: Quicktime, Codec: QT rle / QT animation). I’m on a low end computer: 2,66 GHz. Although the rendering has worked before but not anymore for some reason. I’ve re–installed Blender (2.7.8) without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would have attached an image if I could, but I'm new to this site and I haven't figured out how to to that just yet.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Without seeing your compositing nodes it is going to be hard to help you.

Comment: You mention that the renders are ignoring your compositing nodes and whilst this is obvious, make sure your "Compsiting" box is ticked.  That's under the Render properties icon at the right.  Open the Post Processing tab.

Comment: Sorry folks. I forgot the obvious: to tick the compositing box. Thanks anyway for you people out there that spend your valuable time helping newbies like me.